# TypeError: undefined is not a function (Phaser JS)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi everybody i'm just trying executing a method inside a class and it's not working. 
I got an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error.

I'm calling others functions and it's working well so I don't understand. I've tried to change the name and nothing.

I think that there is a problem with Phaser that I'm using but I've no idea...

```
Bomb.prototype.collisionBlocs = function() {
    if (!this.hasBounced) {
        this.bounce();
        this.hasBounced = true;
    }
}

Bomb.prototype.bounce = function() {       
    if (this.direction == 'UP') {
        this.direction = 'DOWN';
    }
    else if (this.direction == 'RIGHT') {
        this.direction = 'LEFT';
    }
    else if (this.direction == 'DOWN') {
        this.direction = 'UP';
    }
    else if (this.direction == 'LEFT') {
        this.direction = 'RIGHT';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare `bounce() ` before `collisionBlocs()`?

Comment: is it giving you this error when bounce() is invoked?

Comment: In fact, collisionBlocs() is a callback function from a phaser collision events : game.physics.arcade.collide(this.sprite, blocs, this.collisionBlocs); Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Chris I tried but it's not working                                           Yes Liam only when I invoke it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **"In fact, `collisionBlocs()` is a callback function from a phaser collision events : `game.physics.arcade.collide(this.sprite, blocs, this.collisionBlocs);` Maybe that's the problem"**

That *will* be the problem. In JS, the value of `this` within a function depends on how a function is called. You pass a reference to `collisionBlocs` to the `.collide()` method and when it calls it it won't be setting `this` correctly so then `this.bounce` will be `undefined`.

You need to force the value of `this` to be correct. The easiest way to do that is with `.bind()`:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(this.sprite, blocs, this.collisionBlocs.bind(this));
```

The [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is not supported in older browsers (IE <=8), but there is [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) you can use if you need to support those browsers.

MDN has more information on [how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Oh my god it's working thanks you ! I've trouble to understand your explain but I will try... Thanks !

Comment: I've added [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to my answer that gives more detail about how `this` works. I don't really want to put a full explanation of that in my answer because it would just be repeating any number of other tutorials and StackOverflow answers. It's a pretty important concept to understand if you're going to code in JS.

Comment: Yes I saw your link and I'm about understanding the concept. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Rather than binding `this` it would be easier to use the `callbackContext` parameter that `collide` offers you. It was added for specifically this issue. Here's the method signature:

`collide: function (object1, object2, collideCallback, processCallback, callbackContext)`

You're not using `processCallback` so you can pass `null` for that, but you do need the context. This is the context in which the callback will be invoked (try `this` to start with).