# variables undefined after assignment

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am a beginner level javascript programmer. I can't find a reason why there is `undefined` values for the `winX` and `WinY` variables in the following function:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(
  800,
  600,
  Phaser.AUTO,
  'game',
  { init: init,
    preload: preload, 
    create: create, 
    update: update,
    randomizeWin: randomizeWin,
    myMethod: myMethod
  }
);

function init() {
  this.sss=56;
  this.marginX=150;
  this.marinY=100;    
}

function preload() {
  var wood = game.load.image('wood', 'assets/wood.jpg');
  randomizeWin();
  console.log(this.winY);
}

function create() {
  this.p=[];
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    this.p[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
      this.p[i][j]= game.add.sprite(this.marginX+i*170, this.marinY+j*170, 'wood');
      this.p[i][j].scale.x=0.2;
      this.p[i][j].scale.y=0.2;
      this.p[i][j].anchor.setTo(.5,.5);
      this.p[i][j].inputEnabled = true;
      this.p[i][j].input.useHandCursor = true;
      this.p[i][j].events.onInputDown.add(myMethod, this);
    }   
  }
}

function update() {
}

function myMethod(sprite) {
  console.log(this.p[this.winX][this.winY]==sprite);// winX is undefined here why??
  if(this.p[this.winX][this.winY]==sprite){
    game.add.tween(sprite.scale).to ({
      x: sprite.scale.x * -1,
      // y: sprite.scale.y * -1
    }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.Out, true);
  }
}

function randomizeWin() {
  console.log("rand");
  this.winX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  this.winY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}
```

What is happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Just as everyone would expect: You haven't defined it.

Comment: @connexo Unhelpful to a beginner JS programmer, though; as far as he's concerned he *has*. It's an issue of not understand the nature of `this` in JS.

Comment: is it not defined in the randomizeWin() function, sorry but can u explain what should i do

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359415/phaser-this-game-is-undefined-in-the-update-function and / or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760125/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-phaser-js

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` depends on the calling context.

You'd either need to bind the object in question, roughly:

```
this.p[i][j].events.onInputDown.add(myMethod.bind(this), this);
```

(But as your code currently stands this would have the same issue) or rely on whatever the framework in question provides in the way of binding.

Welcome to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` on JS opens up a whole world of pain. You should avoid it until you are really sure [how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or rename it to something else on your scope:

```
var self = this;

function create() {
  self.p = [];
  //etc
}

function randomizeWin(){
  self.winX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  self.winY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function myMethod(sprite){
  console.log(self.p[self.winX][self.winY]==sprite);
}
```

Comment: but i have called `randomizeWin()` before using the variables